# Como colocar um texto ao lado de uma imagem CSS

Tags: html, css, imagem, texto

gostaria de colocar o texto e a imagem lado a lado, sou iniciante e estou aprendendo css e html ainda.

```css
.texto {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  
  color: #ffffff;

  gap: 10px;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="texto">

    <div>
         <img src="foto.png" height="400px"
         alt="">
    </div>
   
    <div class="quem somos">
     
      <h1>QUEM SOMOS?</h1>
      <p>Somos mais do que uma simples loja de roupas; somos uma comunidade apaixonada por estilo, autenticidade e autoexpressão. Fundada com o objetivo de oferecer moda acessível e inspiradora para todos, a TrendyWear tornou-se o destino favorito para aqueles que buscam peças que refletem sua individualidade e personalidade.</p>
     
    </div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Olá, boa tarde depende muito do seu caso completo, mas com o display flex o conteudo já fica em linha mas, como seu texto é grande ele ocupa um espaço que não tem do lado da *img* então ele quebra pra baixo, vc pode limitar o tamanho do texto. De uma forma simplória pode colocar um *max-width: 50%;* na *img*. Além disso classes CSS não podem conter espaços, vc pode usar `-` ou CamelCase como usei no exemplo.

- Dependendo do seu caso pode compensar mudar o width da imagem tambem.
- Lembre de trocar a imagem pela sua.

```css
     .texto {
        display: flex;
        color: #ffffff;
        gap: 10px;
     }
     .quemSomos p{
        max-width: 50%;
     }
```

```html
<div class="texto">

    <div>
         <img src="https://img.freepik.com/vetores-gratis/laptop-com-icone-de-codigo-isometrico-de-programa-desenvolvimento-de-software-e-aplicacoes-de-programacao-neon-escuro_39422-971.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.1.1269040533.1710201600&semt=sph" height="400px" alt="">
    </div>
   
    <div class="quemSomos">
     
      <h1>QUEM SOMOS?</h1>
      <p>Somos mais do que uma simples loja de roupas; somos uma comunidade apaixonada por estilo, autenticidade e autoexpressão. Fundada com o objetivo de oferecer moda acessível e inspiradora para todos, a TrendyWear tornou-se o destino favorito para aqueles que buscam peças que refletem sua individualidade e personalidade.</p>
     
    </div>
```